# can not get back when use UINavigationController in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController which contains UINavigationControllers, whose rootview are UIViewController(name it V1),in the navigation stack, another UIViewController(name it V2) is pushed. The problem is, after event in V1 happens, V2 comes out OK,and then V2 can pop away ok. when do this again, after event in V1 happens, V2 comes out OK, when back button pressed, V2 does not disappear, thought title in UINavigationBarItem has changed.

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Show us the code relevant to the question so that we can help you.

Comment: Yep, let's see the code. Also, it is good to say whether you are using ARC or not, if it is not obvious in the code sample.

Comment: hi,I found the problem, it's because I set the delegate by mistake. Thanks guys.